# Polymer 1.x add input value from script

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having trouble with the polymer in my elements here is my code:

```
 <dom-module id="bb-account-settings">

  <template>

    <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

                <div class="settings-dialog">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="horizontal layout">
                            <div>
                                <div class="user-image"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="horizontal layout">
                                <paper-input label="First Name" value="{{fNameSet}}"></paper-input>
                                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <paper-input label="Last Name" value="{{lNameSet}}"></paper-input>
                            </div>
                            <paper-input label="Email" value="{{emailSet}}"></paper-input>
                        </div>
                        <paper-input label="Phone number" value="{{phoneSet}}" allowed-pattern="[0-9]"></paper-input>
                    </div>
                </div>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'bb-account-settings'

    });

  </script>

<script>

    this.lNameSet = 'test last name'
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('/user/' + userId + '/UserInfo').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        this.fNameSet = snapshot.val().fName;
    });

</script>

</dom-module>
```

As you well think, the first name filed is supposed to be data from firebase and the last name - 'test last name'.

But non of this happens, it doesn't give and error, just doesn't put the fNameSet and lNameSet in place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) should help you understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i'd recommend you to go through polymer [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) or some video guides(if you prefer them).

Comment: hi, I updated my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368392/retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-polymer-element), now I have some new problems...